# Error with ActiveResource and Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I'm using ActiveResource 4.0 to map a RESTFull API to model classes in my Rails 4 Application. Im getting the error **"undefined method 'model_name' for SimpleDelegator:Class"** only when trying to edit an object.

It seems that objects loaded by ActiveResource's descendants are been created as SimpleDelegator's descendants instead - that can't respond to model_name method.

I did some reading on ActiveResource code but I couldn't understand why this is happening. Has anybody stumbled upon something like this?

My Model:

```rb
class Database < ActiveResource::Base
  self.size = "api.endpoint"
end
```

And in my controller (snippet)

```rb
def new
  @database = Database.new
end

def edit
  @database = Database.find(params[:id])
  if !@database
    redirect_to databases_path
  end
end
```

On my form views (snippet):

```rb
<%= form_for @database do |d| %>

  <%= d.label :dbname %> <!-- error reported on this line -->
  <%= @database.dbname %>

  <%= d.label :description %>
  <%= @database.description %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: if somebody has this problem, please upgrade activeresource-response to 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I'm also using the **activeresource-response** gem to get pagination  params sent with HTTP headers.

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/Fivell/activeresource-response/blob/master/lib/active_resource_response/response_method.rb#L61) This gem uses SimpleDelegator to wrap the response after the find method execution to "capture" the full ActiveResource connection's htt_response.

I'll try to fix this in the gem or use another solution, but I think this answer can help someone else.

Comment: it would be great if you provide failing test example.

Comment: Worked with @fivell to solve this issue in activeresource-response gem. Thank you for the fast feedback.